# What is the right way to get a groundtruth custom labeling job output in the augmented manifest file format for a training job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

This page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/augmented-manifest.html has the simple example:

```
{"image-ref": "s3://mybucket/sample01/image1.jpg", "is-a-cat": 1}
{"image-ref": "s3://mybucket/sample02/image2.jpg", "is-a-cat": 0}
```

and says to set `AttributeNames` to `["image-ref", "is-a-cat"]`. This page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-data-output.html says your output file is in `s3://bucket/labeling-job-name/manifests/output/output.manifest`
For my custom labeling job that file has a format like:

```
{
    "source-ref": "s3://bucketname/path/filename.png",
    "job-name": {
        "annotationsFromAllWorkers": "{\"image-similarity\":{\"label\":\"Unrecognizable\"}}"
    },
    "job-name-metadata": {
        "type": "groundtruth/custom",
        "job-name": "job-name-20200221002259",
        "human-annotated": "yes",
        "creation-date": "2020-02-21T00:26:31+0000"
    }
}
```

So the question is, do I need to do something to change the output format in the labeling job, or pass some other kind of data in `AttributeNames` such as `["source-ref", "job-name.annotationsFromAllWorkers.image-similarity.label"]`, or write another script to massage the data into the right format?

Answer (score 0):

The output of SageMaker GroundTruth is able to be consumed directly by training, as the output already in JSON lines format. For those output who is supported by SageMaker training built-in Algorithms, customer wouldn't need to further process output data before feed into model, please find all available built-in algorithms here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/algos.html.
There is no built-in algorithm support for Video/Point-Cloud yet, for those non-support job or the other usecase then built-in algorithm, customer need to further process data for customized usecase before consumption.

For example, the image classification case should follow this instruction to set up model - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/image-classification.html#IC-inputoutput.